# 'soldiers.pubkey.Pubkey' has no attribute 'verify'

Tags: solana-program

1. Which version of Solana SDK supports : from solana.publickey import PublicKey?
2. from solders.pubkey import Pubkey.  solders library does not support verify Pubkey in python.   code // # Verify the signed message
   try:
   username, phantom_wallet_address = signed_message.strip().split(' ', 1)  # Limit the split to 1 occurrence
   if Pubkey.verify(username.encode("utf-8"), signed_message, Pubkey(phantom_wallet_address)):   // error message:  AttributeError: type object 'solders.pubkey.Pubkey' has no attribute 'verify'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.